# Can "it" be modified by the relative pronoun, which or that?

Tags: relative-pronouns

For example,

> 1.Where is it **that** you told me to bring home?
>
> 2.Where is it, **which** you told me to bring home?

("It" is not a place but an object such as bag or apple)

I think both are natural and grammatically correct because as for 1, I need to use "that" so as to specify what is "it" I'm referring to if "you" seem to be not sure what I'm indicating, but as for 2, I don't need to use "that" to specify "it" if "you" have already known well what is "it", so just to add information, "which" seems to be a better choice in this case than "that". But if they are not natural as well as grammatically wrong, though my assumption is possible, could you answer this question with your natural-sounding examples?

Comment: Neither is really "natural" in your context. Native speakers would usually ask *Where is **what** you told me to bring?*. Or maybe ***whatever [it is]** [that you told me to bring]*, but that would tend to imply even more contempt / insouciance regarding the thing you couldn't be bothered to remember the name of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, isn't it grammatically possible to modify "it" with the relative pronoun, which or that?

Comment: @Floret Yes, but not in *your* example sentence. ***What*** *is it* ***that*** *you told me to eat?* would be fine.

Comment: @JasonBassford Isn't "that" modifying "what", not "it"?

Comment: @JasonBassford *That* doesn't modify *it* in your example.

Comment: @Floret How are you defining *modify*?  The question really seems to be about which relative pronouns can go with which types of *w-* words and sentence constructions. Neither works with either sentence in the question. (Although *Where is it **that** you told me to* ***go***? would also have been fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common with *what is*:

> What is it that you said earlier?

and *where is* when *it* is a place, but not when *it* is a thing.

> Where is it that he talked to you?
>
> Where is it that I bought?

Both of these sound like *it* is a place.

*Where is what* is better:

> *Where is what I bought?*

Comment: But strictly speaking, isn't "that" modifying "it", not "what" in your first sentence?